# Convert MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS to Unix Timestamp (SQL)

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm looking for a solution to convert MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS stored dates, in a MySQL table, to Unix timestamps.

Comment: Your first problem is that the datetimes are stored as strings.

Comment: Is it too late to start storing dates as dates?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Unfortunately, I have no control of the data until it's imported - it's all generated from "ancient" technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date is in an odd format you can convert it using `STR_TO_DATE` then use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('08/14/2013 22:12:19','%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s'));
```

You may want to consider switching the stored dates to true dates as this will make using the MySQL date functions simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the date format until it's imported into the database. What would you suggest as the most efficient solution to converting all of the dates in the table (several million), putting the valid dates into a neighbouring column? (or worst case over-writing the existing).

Comment: @eversonjw I would put the dates into a new column and move over the existing, that way if anything goes wrong the old column will still be there. As for efficiency it's perhaps better to ask that as a new question so you can get the best answer.